# Difference between 'ls -ltr abc*' and 'find ./ -name abc*' command?

Tags: linux, find, ls, command

To search a file in a directory, I found two commands as below:

- ls -ltr initialfilename*
- find ./ -name initialfilename*

Sometime, first command gives me the search result but sometime I used to execute second command.
What is the difference between these two set of Linux command? Please specify your answer around the major difference only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `ls -ltr file*`: This command just list the contents of the current directory in the long listing format (`-l`), sorted by modification time (`-t`) in reverse order (`-r`) of all files and directories beginning with `file*`.
- `find ./ -name file*`: That command searches trough the whole directory structure under the current working directory and all its subdirectories for files and directories beginning with `file*` in their names. The output format is very simple; only the file/dir paths are printed line by line.

**Major difference (conclusion):**
`ls` only applies to the current working directory, while `find` applies to all files and subdirectories starting from the current working directory.

Comment: Your answer is better than all but not what I was looking for.

Comment: ursitesion: The answer from @chaos exactly describes what the two commands to and how their outputs differ. If this is not what you had in mind, please give a better explanation of what you are looking for. And how about running these commands and seeing the differences for yourself?

Comment: _ls only applies to the current working directory_ is this correct statement? How about `ls -R` ?

Answer (score 3):

The `find` version will also find files matching that name in subdirectories.

Note you should quote or escape the `*` in the filename pattern; if the pattern matches a file in the local directory it will expand to that name and `find` will only find exactly that name. If it matches more than one filename then you will get an error because those multiple filenames will replace the pattern in the `find` invocation and that doesn't match `find` syntax. E.g.:

```
$ cd /etc
$ find . -name pass*
find: paths must precede expression: passwd-
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
$ find . -name 'pass*'
./passwd
./passwd-
./pam.d/passwd
./cron.daily/passwd
```

Comment: If I quote the filename pattern, I didn't get any result. Also, find list all the  files which match the pattern in command.

Comment: If you quote the filename pattern with `ls` then that's expected, there `ls` does no expansion of filenames but depends on the shell in such cases. In the case of `find` I find it hard to believe that you didn't get any result..

Answer (score 2):

The shell will do filename expansion before either command is executed, so the results depends on what is in your current directory.

To get what you want, I think you wouldwant to quote the `*` in the find command. check this example.

```bsh
# First show all the files
~/tmp/stack $ find .
.
./dir1
./dir1/FileA
./dir1/FileB
./dir1/FileC
./dir1/filec
./dir2
./dir2/filea
./dir2/fileb

# Following will list nothing because there is no file named File* in the current directory
~/tmp/stack $ ls -lR File*
ls: cannot access File*: No such file or directory

# Now using find will work because no file named File* exists, file name 
# expansion fails, so find sees the * on the command line.
~/tmp/stack $ find . -name File*
./dir1/FileA
./dir1/FileB
./dir1/FileC

# I'll create a file named Filexxx
~/tmp/stack $ touch Filexxx

# ls will work but only list details for Filexxx
~/tmp/stack $ ls -lR File*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 christian christian 0 Apr 21 09:08 Filexxx

# and so will find but probably not as expected because filename expansion works, so actual command executed is find . -name Filexxx
~/tmp/stack $ find . -name File*
./Filexxx

# now escape the wild card properly, then find will work as expected
~/tmp/stack $ find . -name File\*
./dir1/FileA
./dir1/FileB
./dir1/FileC
./Filexxx
~/tmp/stack
```

Comment: +1 for "the results depends on what is in your current directory".

Answer (score 0):

`ls -ltr` will list the file if it exists in the current directory. `find` will search for the file recursively (will look for the file in the subdirectories)

Answer (score 0):

The `find`command will fail if the `initialfilename*` expands to more than one files:

```
$ touch initiala initialb
$ dir -lrt initial*
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user 0 0 2015-04-21 10:17 initialb
-rw-rw-rw-  1 user 0 0 2015-04-21 10:17 initiala
$ find . -name initial*
find: paths must precede expression: initialb
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

That's why you should escape the asterisk:

```
$ find . -name "initial*"
./initiala
./initialb

$ find . -name initial\*
./initiala
./initialb
```